# AWS S3 chunked payload chunk size must be multiple of 8 KB?

Tags: amazon-s3, arduino-esp32

I am currently working to implement my AWS S3 http(s) interface on an ESP32 using the arduino framework. In the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-streaming.html) it is written:

> Decide the payload chunk size. You need this when you write the code.
>
> The chunk size must be at least 8 KB. We recommend a chunk size of a
> least 64 KB for better performance. This chunk size applies to all
> chunks except the last one. The last chunk you send can be smaller
> than 8 KB. If your payload is small and can fit into one chunk, then
> it can be smaller than the 8 KB.

So I interpreted, *anything bigger than 8 KB is just fine*. I actually still believe so but the following is the case.

**The problem:**
When I set the chunk payload consisting of 16 KB of payload + 89 bytes of chunk meta, only transmitting files, which are actually smaller than 16 KB - 89 bytes (= 16295 bytes), is possible. This means files bigger than 16295 bytes fail to upload because of a signature mismatch, where the hash of the current payload (the first chunk) of the string to sign, returned from AWS, is different to mine. I checked only hash generators all proving my payload to be hashed correctly.

**The workaround:**
When I change my payload chunk to 16295 bytes instead of plain 16 KB (16384 bytes), each final chunk will have the size of 16384 bytes (= 16295 bytes of payload + 89 bytes of chunk meta). This will allow me to upload any file (I tested only up to 1 MB).

**The question:**
So my question is, why is AWS only able to correctly process my chunks, when they have the exact size of 16384 bytes including payload + meta bytes???

I have not tried other mutliplies of 8 KB and I have not found any hint in the documentation explaining this fact, so I am curious if someone else experienced it differntly.